# Cannot find video plugin: video/x-gst-fourcc-AVin-Decoder

Tags: video, codecs

I try to cut a video in Pitivi and get the following error:

**Missing file: video/x-gst-fourcc-AVin-Decoder**

The problem: I do not find any plugin with that name. Which plugin solves the problem then?

The output of `avconv -i video_filen_ame` is

```
avconv version 0.8.9-6:0.8.9-0ubuntu0.13.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
built on Nov  9 2013 19:09:46 with gcc 4.8.1
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mov':
Metadata:
major_brand     : qt  
minor_version   : 537199360
compatible_brands: qt  
creation_time   : 2013-11-12 15:14:31
Duration: 00:02:00.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 115200 kb/s
Stream #0.0(eng): Video: DV, 1920x1080, 113664 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 25k tbc
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-11-12 15:14:31
Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-11-12 15:14:31
Stream #0.2(eng): Data: tmcd / 0x64636D74
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-11-12 15:16:08
```

Comment: Please add the output of `avconv -i video_filen_ame`. If avconv is not installed use `sudo apt-get install libav-tools`.

Comment: I added the code above.

Comment: Could you upload a sample video?

Answer (score 3):

Decoding of AVin (AVC-Intra format from Avid) is not supported by `gstreamer` & not very well or at all by `libav`. (`libavcodec`, etc.)

It is supported by recent versions of the real `ffmpeg` and possibly some apps built off of it.

A sample file that is probably similar to yours is here:

http://samples.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bugs/trac/ticket524/AVCI50.mov

I can play it fine in a recent `mpv` that uses `ffmpeg`, nothing else can handle. So you may need to re-encode it to something Pitivi can deal with.

Comment: How? I tried tragtor and handbrake. Both did not work.

Comment: You should use the real FFmpeg to convert. Precompiled binaries are avail. in either of the links here - http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html If you wish to build your own FFmpeg then this guide is the best one - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide As far as command to use that should be a new question

Comment: I seem to have the same issue as OP and am under Ubuntu 18.04 (so 5 years later). Wouldn't the latest version of ffmpeg support the `x-gst-fourcc-av01` format? Also, what do you call _"the real ffmpeg"_?

Comment: Ah! I tested on a 22.04 install and it worked with the native installed version. (i.e. `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`). The `snap` version is a bit behind (somehow) and it does not support the format I bumped into! So for newcomers, I suggest testing with Ubuntu 22.04 before you try to recompile ffmpeg.